# Applying udfs on a data drame

Tags: r, apply

I have the following data frame `df` containing two columns of dates.

```
             pnr_date       departuredate
1 06/10/2014 00:00:00 06/11/2014 00:00:00
2 12/06/2013 00:00:00 12/06/2013 00:00:00
3 12/03/2013 00:00:00 12/03/2013 00:00:00
4 03/11/2012 00:00:00 03/12/2012 00:00:00
5 08/29/2011 00:00:00 09/01/2011 00:00:00
6 03/10/2012 00:00:00 03/10/2012 00:00:00
```

I have written two simple functions. One that counts the days between two dates and one that finds which day (Monday,Tuesday etc) is a given date.

```
anticipation<-function(date1,date2){

  ForDate1<-strsplit(date1," ")[[1]][1]
  ForDate2<-strsplit(date2," ")[[1]][1]

  as.numeric(as.POSIXct(parse_date_time(ForDate2,"mdy"))-as.POSIXct(parse_date_time(ForDate1,"mdy")))

}
```

and

```
wDay<-function(date){

  ForDate<-strsplit(date," ")[[1]][1]
  weekdays(as.Date(parse_date_time(ForDate,"mdy")))

}
```

They both use the library `lubridate`.

Is there a way to use `apply()` or similar on the data frame for calculating the amount of days between the two dates of each row (using the function `anticipation()`) and also to find the exact day for all the dates in the second column (using the function `wDay()`)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the **difference in days**, use

```
df$days.between <- as.numeric(
    difftime(
        strptime(df$pnr_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        strptime(df$departuredate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        units = "days"
    )
)
```

e.g.

```
as.numeric(
    difftime(
        strptime("09/01/2011 00:00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        strptime("08/29/2011 00:00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        units = "days"
    )
)
[1] 3
```

To get the **weekday**, use

```
df$weekday <- weekdays(as.Date(df$departuredate))
```

e.g.

```
weekdays(as.Date("09/01/2011 00:00:00"))
[1] "Tuesday"
```

If you want non-English names, you need to set your locale:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")
[1] "de_DE"
weekdays(as.Date("09/01/2011 00:00:00"))
[1] "Dienstag"
```